Azure SAS token does not expire even though expiry is specified
I created a SAS token using the following python function:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas


def generate_sas_token(connection_string: str, container_name: str, blob_name: str, duration: int = 60) -> tuple[str, str]:
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=blob_service_client.account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        account_key=blob_service_client.credential.account_key,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),  # Set the permissions as needed
        expiry=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=duration)  # Set the expiry time as needed
    )
    sas_url = f"https://{blob_service_client.account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas_token}"
    return sas_token, sas_url

As you can see I specify the expiry date by using a 60 minutes offset to the current time. So I would expect the token to be invalid after 60 minutes. However even 2 hours later the SAS token is still valid. I opened the SAS url in another browser in private mode to prevent any browser caching messing sth up but I was still able to download the file just fine.
The documentation mentions that the 'expiry' field can be overwritten by an access policy but I checked my storage account and there are no access policies present.
Is there anything I missed as I don't see any errors in the code?

Your code looks ok to me. Only thing I can think of is the ACL on the container. Is it set to be private or something else. Can you please check?

It actually was not set private before. I just changed that and tried it again. I created a new SAS url with 1 min duration but I can still download it 5 min later.

You see this behavior when the clock on the computer where SAS token is generated is not synchronized with the Azure Storage Server clock. Can you please try in 5 minutes and see if you are still able to access the blob? Try it in a new private browser session to removing browser caching. Also check the request status in browser's dev tools.

I fixed it. Turns out your local timezone does matter. I initally thought it will be just valid from now + X minutes no matter your local timezone however this is not the case. It is valid from a current utc timestamp (by default) until another utc timestamp. If you are in another timzone the SAS token might expire in multiple hours or is already expired. This is due to the fact that datetime.now() creates a timestamp based on the timezone of the machine running the code. But Azure interprets this timestamp as UTC by default.
The best way to solve this is to explicitly use utc time with pytz. This will always work regardless of your local time zone.
Here is the correct code:
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas


def generate_sas_token(connection_string: str, container_name: str, blob_name: str, duration: int = 10) -> tuple[str, str]:
    """Generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for a blob in Azure Blob Storage.

    Args:
        connection_string (str): The connection string for the Azure Blob Storage account.
        container_name (str): The container name where the file is stored.
        blob_name (str): The file name
        duration (int, optional): The duration in minutes how long the SAS token will be valid. Defaults to 10.
        deviation (int, optional): The timzone deviation in hours between UTC and your local timezone. Defaults to 2.

    Returns:
        tuple[str, str]: The SAS token and the SAS URL.
    """
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=blob_service_client.account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        account_key=blob_service_client.credential.account_key,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),  # Set the permissions as needed
        start=datetime.now(pytz.utc),
        expiry=datetime.now(pytz.utc) + timedelta(minutes=duration) 
    )
    sas_url = f"https://{blob_service_client.account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas_token}"
    return sas_token, sas_url

Now it works (or fails in this case) correctly:
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:1234bcdc-600e-001a-210a-e8f0d6000000 Time:2024-08-06T14:10:57.3498993Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Tue, 06 Aug 2024 14:08:57 GMT] - Expiry [Tue, 06 Aug 2024 14:09:57 GMT] - Current [Tue, 06 Aug 2024 14:10:57 GMT]</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>

